# Extend DataAnnotations.DataType enum to include custom data types for MVC templates

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, data-annotations

Is there a way to extend the DataType annotation to include more DataType enum options. Currently it supports basic options such as:

- Custom
- DateTime
- Date
- Duration
- PhoneNumber
- Etc.

I know one can specify a template name as in

```
[DataType("BooleanToYesNo")]
```

But I'm looking for a more concrete approach such as the existing options

```
[DataType(DataType.BooleanToYesNo)]
```

If this was possible it would avoid problems later in the applications lifecycle if we decided to change the name of the template.

Is this possible?